# Tick by Tick Stock Data in Second Intervals

Tags: python, stock, yfinance

Is there a way to get historical tick data from yfinance? I want to analyze a stock in 10 second intervals but I can only access daily data.

Answer (score 0):

I think `yfinance` permits the following time intervals:

```
[1m, 2m, 5m, 15m, 30m, 60m, 90m, 1h, 1d, 5d, 1wk, 1mo, 3mo]
```

To get data in any of the above intervals, you would have to use the `interval` argument. For e.g.

```
df = yf.download('AAPL', start='2023-01-01', end='2023-01-31', interval='2m')
```

`1m` data is available only for `7` backward dates. Other intervals don't seem to have this restriction, though.